# bitlocker recovery triggered, cannot boot windows

Tags: bitlocker, tpm, recovery

I enabled bitlocker on my Alienware 15 R3 in 2018 (win10), protection method is tpm + pin
normally windows would boot after I input the pin
however, a month ago, the system had a freeze. at reboot, it spent some time repairing C: after I input the bitlocker pin, then threw the recovery key screen. i forgot the detailed reason on that screen. long story short, at this moment, recovery key is not with me. a txt of the key is saved on one locked partition..

I have tried ways to bypass the bitlocker recovery screen:
a) disable then re-enable (1) secure boot (2) uefi (3) Firmware TPM

b) change secure boot mode from standard to custom and back to standard

However, none of these was able to bypass the recovery screen. now, the message at recovery screen is: Bitlocker needs your recovery key to unlock your drive because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed.

does secure boot policy mean whatever values in PCR 7 does not match a pre-saved value in bios? i don't know why the mismatch. is it possible to make them match?

Comment: There is no way to bypass the BitLocker recovery screen, if there was a way, the recovery feature wouldn't be worth anything. Now sadly it's in this state due to a system crash, which is the reason, the recovery key being on the same encrypted volume is bad practice.  The only way around it would be to connect the HDD to another computer, unlock the volume, and grab the text file that contains the recovery key.  However, that might not work, due to the protector being used.

Comment: The only way to unlock the volume is the recovery key, right? It's not available. There is some techniques to sniff a vmk from the tpm, but the laptop seems to only equip with a firmware tpm (no physical access for sniff). With a firmware tpm, where is the vmk saved?

Comment: I maintain you are likely not going to be able to do what you are attempting to do.  I wouldn't know how to access the fTPM, even if you could, that still would NOT provide you the recovery key.  Which would still be needed.

Comment: Thank you for reply though.